# Nothing in allure report with cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin 4.0.0 and cucumber 2

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, allure

I run parallel test with forked jvm with maven-surefire-plugin
and cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin. My pom.xm fragment https://pastebin.com/98RxWrKX

Tests are run correct and all run correct. But my allure reusults are blank when i run parallel tests. And there are alright when I run my test in single mode.

I need help with adding `io.qameta.allure.cucumber2jvm.AllureCucumber2Jvm` plugin to my project.

PS
I cant use cucumber-jvm 4 (with build-in parallel) due to external dependency of my project&

To run single test I use:

```
mvn -am -pl bdd_test test -DENV=ENV -P parallel "-Dcucumber.options=--tags @SomeTags --plugin pretty"
```

To run parallel I use:

```
mvn -am -pl bdd_test test -DENV=ENV -P parallel "-Dcucumber.options=--tags @PP --plugin pretty"
```

versions:
maven.surefire.plugin.version=2.20
cucumber.jvm.parallel.plugin.version=4.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I found that cmd  `--plugin pretty` override all plugins section in parallel plugin -> so there is no Allure plugin started.

Correct command:

```
mvn -am -pl bdd_test test -DENV=ENV -P parallel "-Dcucumber.options=--tags @PP"
```

And define all plugins in pom.xml